# How to do Type Inference using an SMT solver?

Tags: sat, type-theory

I understand that Hindley-Milner Type Inference can be implemented using an off-the-shelf SMT (Satisfiability Modulo Theories) solver?

How would this work, for example for a very simple type system (just primitive base types and function types, no polymorphism, no subtyping, no nuthin')?

Comment: You can think of type inference as a unification problem. If your SMT solver can do unification, that's pretty much it. There isn't any logic involved, just a bunch of equations.

Comment: Could people who are downvoting this please explain their downvotes? I realize this is probably not research-level, but an explanation would still be nice, thanks.

Comment: FWIW, I my opinion "no polymorphism" means "not Hindley-Milner", since the key element of HM is how to automatically introduce (and eliminate) polymorphism.

Comment: I found [a recent paper](https://www.ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/infk/chair-program-method/pm/documents/Education/Theses/Mostafa_Hassan_BA_report.pdf) describing type inference for Python 3 using an SMT solver.